# Laravel - How to hide div element based on dropdownlist value

Tags: laravel

I have this Laravel-5.8 code in my Web Application Project

Controller

```
public function create()
{
  $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;   
  $goaltypes   =       AppraisalGoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
  $categories = AppraisalGoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNotNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('goals.create')
        ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

view blade

```html
 <form  action="{{route('goals.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                  <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card card-outline card-info">
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body pad">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <textarea class="textarea" name="goal_description" rows="15" placeholder="Enter goal description here ...
                      style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

The dropdown list is a foreign key derived from another table.

What I want to achieve is that on change,

> if {{ $child->name }} is "Simon"

Then the div for the **textarea** of **goal_description** should be hidden.

How do I get achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do it :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>       
    $(document).ready(function () {              
    $('select').on('change', function() {
                    if( this.value === 'Simon') $('.textarea').hide();
                });
    });
</script>
```

**Explanations :**

First script load the librairie Jquery in your page
Second script, once dom is ready, the "onchange" event of select will call compare the current value with 'Simon', if it's equal, the textarea ll be hidden.